# ERROR when compile using Nodejs webpack compile:scss error

Tags: node.js, webpack

i have the following error when run this npm run compile:js i get this error:

```
> sfra@6.0.0 compile:scss
> sgmf-scripts --compile css

C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\NewTry\trainingb2c\node_modules\webpack\lib\ChunkGraph.js:1679
                                        throw new Error(
                                        ^

Error: Chunk.getNumberOfModulesThere was no ChunkGraph assigned to the Chunk for backward-compat (Use the new API)
    at deprecated (node:internal/util:89:15)
    at Function.getChunkGraphForChunk (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\NewTry\trainingb2c\node_modules\webpack\lib\ChunkGraph.js:1689:10)
    at Chunk.getNumberOfModules (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\NewTry\trainingb2c\node_modules\webpack\lib\Chunk.js:170:21)
    at ExtractTextPlugin.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\NewTry\trainingb2c\node_modules\extract-text-webpack-plugin\dist\index.js:302:30)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\NewTry\trainingb2c\node_modules\extract-text-webpack-plugin\dist\index.js:301:25
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\NewTry\trainingb2c\node_modules\sgmf-scripts\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:7:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\NewTry\trainingb2c\node_modules\sgmf-scripts\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:154:20)
    at C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\NewTry\trainingb2c\node_modules\sgmf-scripts\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1405:32
```

this is my webpack.config.js:

[webpack.config.js](https://gist.github.com/luisphp/ec1e8f1ff04c29bcf3d4d411beede79d)

Some idea to solve? thanks in advance

Comment: The log say in the first line "There was no ChunkGraph assigned to the Chunk for backward-compat " so this is causing in cascate all the others

Comment: thanks for the help, i just ask a colleague and he passed me a new package.json with other versions of dependencies i set that version in my package.json and problem solved

Comment: Well, indeed even the error said "Use the new API", deprecated. Glad you find a solution

Comment: It's not very helpful when it says 'Use the new API' if you don't know which API that is!